# Facing issue in HTTPClient post method in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I'm facing issue with http call.

Error Message is : `httpclient postasync an error occurred while sending the request`

```
 public TResult PostAPI<T>(string url, T reqparams, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> formParameters = null, string jsonString = "", List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> headers = null)
    {
        HttpContent contentPost = null;
        if (headers != null)
        {
            AddHeaders(headers);
        }
        if (formParameters != null)
        {
            var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formParameters);
            contentPost = formContent;

        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonString))
        {
            var content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            contentPost = content;
        }

        string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reqparams);
        var contents = new StringContent(s, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        contentPost = contents;

        //client. = 3000;
        var response = client.PostAsync(url, contentPost).Result; //Task.Run(() => client.PostAsync(url, contentPost)).Result;

        IEnumerable<string> responseHeaders;
        response.Headers.TryGetValues("Authorization", out responseHeaders);

        if (responseHeaders != null && responseHeaders.Any())
        {
            AccessToken = responseHeaders.Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        var apiResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(apiResult);
        return result;
    }
```

**Throw this error:**

> at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+d__63.MoveNext () [0x004ab] in <7736395a6c71409691a34accfc621095>:0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+d__49.MoveNext () [0x000ca] in <7736395a6c71409691a34accfc621095>:0

Comment: Try setting an exception breakpoint on System.Exception. That should give you a more detailed error.

Comment: That is not the entire stack trace. Also provide the Exception message. It is unclear from your error description what is wrong.

Comment: error message is : `httpclient postasync an error occurred while sending the request`